# How do I use a Converter in my binding without it throwing a "FormatException"?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, ivalueconverter

Using my Converter throws a 'FormatException' with the message 'Input String was not in a correct format'. In the Troubleshooting Tips, it says 'When Converting a string to DateTime, parse the string to take the date before putting each variable into the DateTime object'. Does that tip always come up? Because I'm not using a DateTime object in the Converter, though it is used elsewhere in MainWindow.

I have a UserControl in my MainWindow:

```
<local:dCB_Props x:Name="cbTags" Height="23" VerticalAlignment="Top" AddClick="cbTags_AddClick" EditClick="cbTags_EditClick" />
```

I dynamically add items to it, the type of which is another UserControl, called EditDeleteItem. I set it's DataTemplate to the one below:

```
<DataTemplate x:Shared="false" x:Key="TagTemplate">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Label, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        <CheckBox Style="{DynamicResource DaisyCheckBox}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Content="Isolated">
            <CheckBox.IsChecked>
                <Binding Path="TagSearchOptions.TagPosition" Converter="{StaticResource TagPosConverter}"/>
            </CheckBox.IsChecked>
        </CheckBox>
        <CheckBox Style="{DynamicResource DaisyCheckBox}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Content="Match Case" />
        <CheckBox Style="{DynamicResource DaisyCheckBox}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Content="Include" />
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

My Converter is:

```
public class TPositionToBoolConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if(value!=null)
        {
        }
        return false;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return TagPosition.Anywhere;
    }
}
```

Below is the Key in the resource dictionary

```
<local:TPositionToBoolConverter x:Key="TagPosConverter"/>
```

I will change the code in the converter when it works properly. I should mention that it doesn't throw an exception if I remove the converter.

Thanks In advance.

### Update:

I changed the code for the `Convert` Method, it now returns `false` instead of `"false"`. I should mention I was returning a bool first, but as a last resort and after trying other things, I attempted to return a string but forgot to change it back when writing this question.

### Update 2:

The stack trace:

> at System.Text.StringBuilder.AppendFormat(IFormatProvider provider,
>   String format, Object[] args)    at
>   System.String.Format(IFormatProvider provider, String format, Object[]
>   args)    at
>   System.Diagnostics.TraceListener.TraceEvent(TraceEventCache
>   eventCache, String source, TraceEventType eventType, Int32 id, String
>   format, Object[] args)    at
>   System.Diagnostics.TraceSource.TraceEvent(TraceEventType eventType,
>   Int32 id, String format, Object[] args)    at
>   MS.Internal.AvTrace.Trace(TraceEventType type, Int32 eventId, String
>   message, String[] labels, Object[] parameters)    at
>   MS.Internal.TraceData.Trace(TraceEventType type, AvTraceDetails
>   traceDetails, Object p1, Object p2)    at
>   System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.UpdateSource(Object value)    at
>   System.Windows.Data.BindingExpressionBase.UpdateValue()    at
>   System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.SetValue(DependencyObject d,
>   DependencyProperty dp, Object value)    at
>   System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueCommon(DependencyProperty dp,
>   Object value, PropertyMetadata metadata, Boolean
>   coerceWithDeferredReference, OperationType operationType, Boolean
>   isInternal)    at
>   System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValue(DependencyProperty dp, Object
>   value)    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ToggleButton.set_IsChecked(Nullable`1
>   value)    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ToggleButton.OnToggle()    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ToggleButton.OnClick()    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnMouseLeftButtonDown(MouseButtonEventArgs
>   e)    at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate
>   handler, Object target)    at
>   System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source,
>   RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)    at
>   System.Windows.UIElement.ReRaiseEventAs(DependencyObject sender,
>   RoutedEventArgs args, RoutedEvent newEvent)    at
>   System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseDownThunk(Object sender,
>   MouseButtonEventArgs e)    at
>   System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object
>   target)    at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object
>   source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)    at
>   System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender,
>   RoutedEventArgs args)    at
>   System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean
>   trusted)    at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()

### Solution

I found the problem. In the resource dictionary the key for the converter should have been above the DataTemplate. I assumed it would have worked regardless of its placement.

Comment: Did you try to use a debugger and see which line is throwing? If not, why?

Comment: I added a breakpoint on the line `public object Convert` but it doesn't seem to break there. It also says No Source Available. I have a library it links to, but I doubt it's that.

Comment: @user1126927: well, if it doesn't break there, I would assume the problem is not with that code, but with some other code you didn't post.

Comment: I've added the stack trace. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your converter should return a boolean, not a string.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I did initially, as a last resort I returned a string. I'll update the code in the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried returning a Boolean object instead of a string representation for it?

```
public class TPositionToBoolConverter : IValueConverter 
{     
   public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)     
{         
   if(value!=null)         
   {
   }
    return false;
}      

   public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)     
   {         
       return TagPosition.Anywhere;     
   } 
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I did initially, as a last resort I returned a string. I'll update the code in the OP.

Answer (score 0):

[ToggleButton.IsChecked Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.togglebutton.ischecked.aspx) awaits a `Nullable<bool>` / `bool?` from your Converter.

Comment: I changed the code in the OP. It's still throwing the exception. Thanks.

Comment: What about `TagPosition`? Maybe the problem is in `ConvertBack`. Could you post the code of this class?

Comment: Thanks for the help but I finally figured it out. I was using a `DataTemplate` which used the converter and both were in the same Resource Dictionary. It didn't work when the Key to the Converter was listed after the Template, but did when it was listed before.

Answer (score 0):

To spell it out

```
 if(value!=null) return true; else return false;
```

Comment: ...which shortens to just `return (value != null);`

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear, but I'm going to add more code once it doesn't throw errors. Thanks.

Comment: @Vlad I wanted to show the differnce between false and "false"